# Artificial Neural Network with output matrix

Tags: neural-network

I try to understand neural nets and I have the following problem.
I have an Image as the Input. Lets say 3x100x50. And I want that the output is a 100x50 Matrix.
I want to add Convolutional layer between input and output. For example:

Kernel_size: 10
stride: 5
zero-padding: 0
Filters: 4

I think, if I use this Convolutional layer on my input, i get 200 matrix which have a size of 4x10x10, connected to the input - right?

My question is how do I get one matrix of size 100x50 so that it would fit to my ouput?

Comment: i'm not sure you will get 200 matrices... more like 4 (one for every filter)

Comment: i thought i will get one 10x10 matrix for every stride-step.

Comment: One receptive field will compute the value for óne neuron

Comment: I think I get a 10x10 matrix (kernel_size) for every stride-step and these 4 times for every filter - or better I get a 4x10x10 Matrix (4 for the filter).I get 20 matrices horizontal times 10 matrices vertically. So I get 20x10 = 200 Matrices with size of 10x10 and each with 4 filters.

Comment: No, you wont. Oke so for one filter you will get 200x10x10 values. That is WAY more than the input size (3x100x50). You are convoluting your data, so with your (4) receptive fields (size 10, stride 5) you will get 4 matrices of approx. 20x10 neurons. _A receptivd field should reduce the data, not increase it_.